# Pandas - Performing a Groupby at 2 different level

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, data-processing

I'm trying to apply a double groupby on a dataframe in order to gather elements of two columns into list inside two different columns.

I have a dataframe:

```
stack = (
    pd.DataFrame([
        ['source1', 'text...', 12.0],
        ['source1', 'text...', 100.0],
        ['source2', 'text...', 12.0],
        ['source1', 'text...', 24.0],
        ['source2', 'text...', 2.0],
        ['source3', 'text...', 48.0]],
        columns=['source_id', 'content', 'eng']))
```

What I doing so far is grouping by "source_id" the "eng" column in order to have them all inside a list:

```
stack1 = (
    stack.groupby('source_id')['eng']
    .apply(np.array)
    .to_frame('eng')
    .reset_index()
)
```

Which gives:
[image]

Then, I'm doing the same process to gather the "content" column inside a list:

```
stack2 = (
    stack.groupby('source_id')['content']
    .apply(np.array)
    .to_frame('content')
    .reset_index()
)
```

Which gives:
[image]

What I'm trying is to do both action into one operation in order to achieve a dataframe like this:

```
final = (
    pd.DataFrame([
        ['source1', ['text...', 'text...', 'text...'], [12.0, 100.0, 24.0]],
        ['source2', ['text...', 'text...'], [12.0, 2.0]],
        ['source3', ['text...'], [48.0]]],
        columns=['source_id', 'content', 'eng']))
```

Which you give this:
[image]

My main objective is to then being able to map the element of "content" to "eng". The order has to remain fixed. I'm not sure that splitting this operation is secure for keeping the original order within lists.

Comment: You can aggregate multiple things at once: `stack.groupby('source_id')[['content', 'eng']].agg(list)`. It's the same groupby object so order is maintained... On the other hand why? Maintaining relationships between lists in different Series is a nightmare in `pandas`. There might be (probably is) a much better way to solve the problem you want to solve instead of going down this path.

Comment: @ALollz Thanks for your answer. The reason why I'm doing this is to being able to perform a QuantileTransformer (sklearn) on the "eng" list. I need a uniform distribution. And to do so, I need to gather all my "eng" number into a list, gather by "source_id". But I also need to keep my the content on the other side for further analysis

Comment: @G.Anderson That'd be easier, indeed.... But I need to perform a sklearn.preprocessing.QuantileTransformer on the "eng" column. Do you think I still could do this with your method?

Comment: I had suggested zipping to preserve order before you added your explanatory comment. It might still work for mapping the elements for other analysis, but it doesn't seem like it would work for you transformation